# Java SE Maven project using ResourceBundle for internationalization

Tags: java, maven, localization

I'm working on a Swing application that has to be localized.

For that purpose, I'm using a `resourceBundle`.  It works fine when I run the application from the IDE.  But when I use `maven` to generate the jar, the application starts up normally but the internationalization stops working.  Without throwing any exception, I have make a lot of variations to solve that problem; I even have make a class that inherits from `java.util.ResourceBundle.Control`.  The only thing I've achieved to make it work is by placing the properties files outside the package (I place it into the desktop just for testing).  I then try to use the same method by specifying the path `by new File(".").getAbsolutePath()`.

Doing that still keeps working from running it from Eclipse, but when I try to generate the jar and execute it, it throws an exception and the application does not start.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you place your properties file into `src/main/java` next to the Java code, Maven will probably not pick it up.

The canonical location would be `src/main/resources` (with the package structure below that duplicated just as it is now in your code).

Comment: I have do that but still not working, the most it do i can do in that way is that it gets the default properties, however much i set a locale to the resourceBundle it still retrieves the default, it is curious becouse runing it from eclipse goes well and i can even change the language in runtime, but when i execute it from jar, seems to be no way to achieve that, maybe if i can't get in this way i can inherit from ResourceBundle.Control the only thing then is that i will need to read a file that is inside a .jar, i can do this or place the language properties into the user home folder.